# How to initialise a C struct without generating warnings when compiling with the GCC "-Wextra" option?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct STest
{
  unsigned int uiRoll;
  unsigned short usiVal;
} TTest;

int main()
{
  TTest oTest = {0};  /* Initialize the Values with 0 */
  printf( "The values are: %d, %d\n", oTest.uiRoll, oTest.usiVal );
  return 0;
}
```

Observation:

1. Compiling with `gcc -Wextra -o a aa.cpp`
2. Getting warning: `warning: missing initializer for member STest::usiVal`
3. I also tried with memset function but still getting the same warning.
4. There is no warning message for first structure element.

How can I initialize the structure? so that there is no warning message.

Comment: With `-Wno-missing-field-initializers`?

Comment: using `gcc x.c` OR `g++ x.cpp` will prevent a lot of future messages

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The advice is good. Use the proper invocation of the compiler, compile C++ source with g++, and C source with gcc. You can of course compile C++ source by invoking gcc, but then you need to pass a lot of options by hand to get the better behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you initialize both members?

```
TTest oTest = {0, 0};
```

Or, possibly better:

```
TTest oTest = { .uiRoll = 0, .usiVal = 0};
```

(This assumes that you are indeed writing C code, which should be compiled with `gcc` and saved with an extension that is  `.c`. If you save that code in a file with a `.cpp` extension, `gcc` will switch to C++ mode, and fail on that second version.)

Another option: upgrade your compiler to GCC >= 4.7.2 (possibly plain 4.7.0 would be enough). That warning is removed and you can use the short form you have in your code.

Comment: That is not always possible, as if you have a structure with a big number of elements and lots of nested structures. Then it will be a big issue to initialize all the member variables..

Comment: @Subhajit Then compile C as C. C has no problems with only one explicit initialiser, 6.7.9 (19) specifies that all other fields/elements are initialised to an appropriate zero value.

Comment: @Daniel: GCC still warns for that, for versions 4.5 and 4.6.3 at least. 4.7 and 4.8 are ok.

Comment: @Mat Oh, that screams bug. Well, gcc had several issues with daft warnings, so I guess I shouldn't be _too_ surprised.

Answer (score 1):

This notation is the most *portable/correct* way to zero initialize a structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct STest
{
  unsigned int uiRoll;
  unsigned short usiVal;
}              TTest;

int main()
{
  /* Static declaration causes structure member's to be zeroed at instantiation */
  static const TTest zeroed_struct;

  /* Structure assignment is then safely used */
  TTest oTest = zeroed_struct;
  printf( "The values are: %d, %d\n", oTest.uiRoll, oTest.usiVal );
  return (0);
}
```

Declaring a *static* `TTest` structure causes the compiler to automatically set all the structure fields to zero. You can then safely use the *assignment operator* to initialize another instance of your structure's members to zero.

It seems to me that using the *universal zero initializer* like you did is correct. Nevertheless, I found this interesting post on the GCC bugtracker which would explain why a warning is issued on your version of GCC, probably version 4.4: [Bug 53119 - -Wmissing-braces wrongly warns about universal zero initializer {0}](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53119).

Answer (score 0):

or even:

```
TTest oTest;
memset(&oTest, 0, sizeof(oTest));
```

I don't get a warning. How did you try to use memset?

Comment: This notation has the disadvantage of being non portable, using the universal zero initializer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Aside of the fact that GCC in this case is could actually be right, the general rule of thumb to disable warnings is to add `no-` prefix to an option that controls emission of a warning message for a particular case. For example, if you read gcc's manual page, it has the following:

> An aggregate has an initializer which does not initialize all members.
>   This warning can be independently controlled by
>   -Wmissing-field-initializers.

Therefore, in order to disable this option, you have to pass `-Wno-missing-field-initializers` to GCC.

Interestingly enough, GCC 4.2.1 issues this warning while GCC 4.7.2 does not, even if that warning is enabled explicitly. After a bit more experimentation, it seems like if you specify a single `0`, no warning is given. However, if you specify two or more fields but not all of them, the warning is there.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: This seems to be a bug reported and validated by the GCC team at the time : http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53119. Which would explain why this warning is not issued in `4.7.2` anymore.